# Which info is shared while a project is bound to TFS or GIT?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, alm

I'm aware that while working on a solution which is versioned (under Git or TFS) the edits cannot be shown remotely until they are "pushed" to the remote repository.

Apart from that, I wonder if the TFS/GIT binding imply sending some other info about who has the project open and when. Let's suppose that 5 teammates have all access to the same remote repository, and they all have their copy of the project downloaded on local folders and versioned.
Can they see who has opened the project and made changes locally (as far as they are all connected to the internet)?

Comment: Git is a decentralized VCS so their is no 'binding'. So except when you receive commits (fetch or pull) or send (push), there is no data exchanged. No way to know what other users do. But it seems that you have something in mind and perhaps you should ask this question...

Comment: To sum up @Philippe's comment: Which Info is shared? None. Can other users see before push? No. :D